# Understanding an Invoke-WebRequest call with output from Fiddler

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to upload an XML config file to a Netgate router, and the page they give you is a php form. This is a normal config file upload with the GUI - when I use the GUI page, Fiddler shows that the exchange looks like this (I note that the form data is typed and the value is a file):

[image: Fiddler - using the GUI]

I try throwing this at the invoke-web request:

```
$RestoreArguments =  @{
    __csrf_magic=$LoopCsrfToken;
    #nopackages=$true;
    #donotbackuprrd=$true;
    donotbackuprrd='yes';
    #encrypt=$false;
    encrypt_password='';
    conffile=[xml](get-content $conffile);
    switch_safe_restore=$true;
    #decrypt=$true;
    decrypt_password=$LoopPW;
    restorearea=$RestoreArea;
    backuparea='';
    restore='Restore Configuration'
    }
$LoopResult = Invoke-WebRequest -timeoutsec 5 -WebSession $LoopSession -Uri "$Luri/diag_backup.php" -Method 'Post' -Body $RestoreArguments
```

and Fiddler capture this:

[image: Fiddler - PS attempt 1]

I thought that maybe the issue is how it's getting the content, so I replaced the conffile parameter like this:

```
conffile=[xml](get-content $conffile);
```

but see Fiddler capture:

[image: Fiddler - PS attempt 2]

So now I think that it is how the parameter is typed, but am not sure how to give the page what it wants.  As a sidenote, no errors from the code. Thank you for your thoughts!

**UPDATE:**
after removing the typecasting from
`conffile=[xml](get-content $conffile);`
to
`conffile=get-item $conffile;`

the value does not show as a file, but a path:

[Fiddler - PS attempt 3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hD84G.png)

**UPDATE 2:**

just so that there is no confusion, I tried this code...

```
$RestoreArguments =  @{
    __csrf_magic=$LoopCsrfToken
    donotbackuprrd='yes'
    encrypt_password=''
    conffile=get-item -path $conffile
    decrypt_password=''
    restorearea=$RestoreArea
    backuparea=''
    restore='Restore Configuration'
    }
$LoopResult = Invoke-WebRequest -TimeoutSec $Timeout -WebSession $LoopSession -Uri "$Luri/diag_backup.php" -Method 'POST' -Body $RestoreArguments
```

and this code...

```
$RestoreArguments =  @{
    __csrf_magic=$LoopCsrfToken;
    donotbackuprrd='yes';
    encrypt_password='';
    conffile=get-item -path $conffile;
    decrypt_password='';
    restorearea=$RestoreArea;
    backuparea='';
    restore='Restore Configuration'
    }
$LoopResult = Invoke-WebRequest -TimeoutSec $Timeout -WebSession $LoopSession -Uri "$Luri/diag_backup.php" -Method 'POST' -Body $RestoreArguments
```

... and both instances don't actually perform the upload. In Fiddler, they yield this output:

[image]

Comment: Are you trying to pass the file, or the file's contents to the page?

Comment: Just pass the file I think. I initially thought that the file's path was sufficient, but now I'm thinking there is more to it than that. As a followup question, if I look at https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/invoke-webrequest?view=powershell-7, should I be successful if I incorporate example 5 or 6? I.E., which example would work in this case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The content-type of your ideal HTTP POST request is multipart/form-data. You need to match that. And the value of the conffile key-value pair must be properly encoded.

Look at [Example 6: Simplified Multipart/Form-Data Submission](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/invoke-webrequest?view=powershell-7#examples) and note the usage of the `-Form` parameter instead the `-Body` parameter. Using that, PS takes care of encoding any value that is a file object (`[System.IO.FileInfo]`).

```perl
$Uri = 'https://api.contoso.com/v2/profile'
$Form = @{
    firstName  = 'John'
    lastName   = 'Doe'
    email      = 'john.doe@contoso.com'
    avatar     = Get-Item -Path 'c:\Pictures\jdoe.png'
    birthday   = '1980-10-15'
    hobbies    = 'Hiking','Fishing','Jogging'
}
$Result = Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $Uri -Method Post -Form $Form
```

Comment: If I do that, I get an error Invoke-WebRequest : A parameter cannot be found that matches parameter name 'form'.

Comment: This happens when I preload PS v7 also BTW.

Comment: Oh, that is only available in PS7. I didn't notice that. But with PS7 it works. What's your `$PSVersionTable.GitCommitId` in PS7?

Comment: It is 7.0.3 - thanks for checking

Comment: SO you were right Daniel - it only was not working for me because I was running ISE and trying to invoke powershell 7 in a session. Running it in Powershell 7 does the job. THANK YOU THANK YOU THANK YOU!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to pass the file itself, not the content of the file, you need to tell PowerShell to get the file using `Get-Item` not the file's content using `Get-Content`.

When you specify `[xml]` that tells PowerShell that the data in what's being returned from `(Get-Content $conffile)` is XML data, and that PowerShell should validate it as such. So you're telling PowerShell to set `$RestoreArguments.conffile` to the XML *within* the file `$conffile`, rather than telling it to send the XML file $conffile to the site.

The rest of your code looks fine, but I can't be sure without actually passing it to the site you're using.
You just need to update the one line for `$RestoreArguments.conffile` from:

```
conffile=[xml](get-content $conffile);
```

to:

```
confFile = Get-Item -Path $confFile;
```

See here for more information about the differences between [Get-Item](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-item?view=powershell-7) and [Get-Content](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-content?view=powershell-7)

Comment: Thanks Crash - I tried making that change, but to no avail. I posted it in the UPDATE section in the original post

Comment: The updated code you posted still shows Get-Content, not Get-Item. Did you make that change in addition to removing the [Xml] type?

Comment: I did make the change - I'm just a moran and didn't type the post as I used it. I edited the update so that it shows get-item

Comment: Thanks again for looking at it - where I am stuck is that this kind of submission is submitting a path as a value. When I submit manually, the value is <file>, which I think is file content (?), but I don't know if there's a PS way to satisfy that value